# EUR/PLN and EUR/USD delta-term-vol surface quoting convension

Tags: volatility, fx, forward, delta

does anyone know for sure what is the FX market convension to quote delta-term pairs for EUR/PLN, for EUR/USD. I know that for EUR/PLN it should be delta p.a forward, for EUR/USD it should be delta spot to 1y and delta fwd from 1y ahead.
but I am not sure from my results, particularly for EUR/PLN pair.